# Battery Capacity Rating

Tags: batteries

I came across valve regulated lead acid batteries with the capacity rated as 112w at a 30 minute rate. 
Im not sure what this means. Can anyone please help me further understand this method of rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batteries, especially older types like Lead Acid, can supply a certain amount of energy, which depends on the current drawn.

The internal resistance causes waste inside the battery, so at a very high current the energy that comes out in total is lower than at lower currents, because more "stays in the internal resistance". It also has to do a little bit with chemical reluctance, but we can leave that out.

Usually batteries specified at ##W over ##min are types that are meant for deep cycling and the number allows a designer to assume that energy over that timespan.

If you want you can convert that rating to an approximation of Ah by calculating the Wh and then dividing by the median battery voltage:

30min at 112W => 56Wh =(2.15V/cell)=> 56Wh / 12.9V =~ 4.34Ah (at 30min = 8.68A for 30min)

But the battery can easily be one that would be specified at 7Ah or even more, because normal (non deep cycle?) batteries are rated at 1/20th, or sometimes 1/10th) the current draw that is their capacity, so a 20Ah would be tested at 1A current draw. And as told before, the higher the current the less energy you can get out of them.

Comment: that would explain why that the same battery is rated as 9Ah even though the conversion gives you 3.75Ah.

Comment: @NadishkaPerera Yup, the high-current performance is horrible for many battery types. Even LiPo batteries see a decent drop in usable capacity when you use a "20C pack" at the 20C rating. (Since they too are specced at 1C, 1/5th C or 1/10th C depending on the quality of the supplier)

Answer (score 0):

112 Watt for 30 minutes can be converted as 56 Whr. It means the battery can provide power of 56 Watt for one hour.

Suppose your device is drawing 14 watt per hour, then the battery will last for 4 hours.

In other case if the device is drawing 7 watt per hour, then the same battery will last for 8 hours